# Strategy for passing in optional arguments to remotely accessed CFC's

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-2016

I know that in ColdFusion, making the access level of a function `remote` means that all arguments are required.  How do I correctly deal with optional arguments?  Often we are getting requests sent to these functions with:

```
?method=doSomething&requiredArg="something"&optionalArg1=&optionalArg2=
```

Is the only way to deal with this making the `type` of the argument in the function "any" or "string" and doing type checking in the code?  I'm considering building an master "remoteApiCFC" that does this with a function and running it on every remote function to get a `local.arguments` struct.  Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you invoking the CFC? It would help to see some code.  Using "remote" doesn't make function arguments required [unless it's used as a web service](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-a-b/cfargument.html) and there's no `default` value defined for the argument:  *...All arguments are required when invoked as a web service, irrespective of how they are defined.Specifies whether the parameter is required to execute the component method. The parameter is not required if you specify a default attribute.*

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define optional arguments for a method:

```
remote string function foo (
    required string bar,
    string option1="optional") {

    return(bar & option1);
}
```